# Strange behavior on the heat equation

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I am having the following problem with the numerical solution of the heat equation.

```
mu = 1; sigma2 = 1; escala = 4; mu2 = 1; sigma3 = 1; escala2 = 0.87; \
Y = 50^(1/3);

T[z_] = z*0.0417*Y^(0.44)*escala2*
   NIntegrate[
    Exp[-(Log[y] - mu2)^2/(2*sigma3^2)]/(Sqrt[2*Pi]*sigma3*y), {y, 0, 
     z}];
P[t_] = 3.18*Y^(0.56)*4.184*10^12*escala*
   Exp[-(Log[t] - mu)^2/(2*sigma2^2)]/(Sqrt[2*Pi]*sigma2*t);
k = 15*10^(-3);
sol = NDSolve[{D[u[x, y, z, t], t] == 
    k*(D[u[x, y, z, t], {x, 2}] + D[u[x, y, z, t], {y, 2}] + 
        D[u[x, y, z, t], {z, 2}]) + 
     NeumannValue[
      Piecewise[{{1105*P[T[t]/T[1]]/(k*(x^2 + y^2 + 1105^2)^(3/2)), 
         t > 0}}, 0], z == 0] + 
     NeumannValue[0, 
      x == -22072/2 || y == -22072/2 || z == 10000 || x == 22072/2 || 
       y == 22072/2], u[x, y, z, 0] == 0}, 
  u, {t, 0, 100}, {x, -22072/2, 22072/2}, {y, -22072/2, 22072/2}, {z, 
   0, 10000}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement"}}]
```

Which results in the following graph:

[image: heat distribution]

The ideia is that a region, initially at 0 degrees temperature, is being heated at the boundary (z==0)  according to the P[T[t]/T[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVU1N.jpg)] expression. However, despite that expression being positive along all the domain (as shown in the graph below), there seems to be no only (strange) discontinuities (those vertical lines on the graph above), but also negative values, that should not appear on the solution, since the region in being heated and not cooled.

Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: What the hell is this thing anyway? Have you bothered to write it in a normalized way? So that region would be of the order of 1 and boundary values as well?

Comment: If you mean the domain, it is {t, 0, 100}, {x, -22072/2, 22072/2}, {y, -22072/2, 22072/2}, {z,    0, 10000}. Could you please elaborate on what it is a normalised way and a region of order 1?

Comment: Make variables substitution so that the domain would be like {x,-1,1} and so on.

Comment: When I run this I get an error message: `NIntegrate::nlim: y = z is not a valid limit of integration.`  You should provide the exact code that you used to compute this.

Comment: This is the exact code and it runs on my computer. I took the error message as only a warning, since the operation that I want to compute is of the type $T[z]=\int_0^z f(y) dy$. Despite the warning, I was able to generate the 2nd graph in my original publication.